# Deleting an IBM Bluemix Internet of things services gives an error

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot

I'm working on a Bluemix Internet of Things (IoT) project and want to delete an IoT service. Bluemix returns:

> Service broker error: Calling url
>   https://bluemix-staging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/broker/v2/service_instances/2a98b0e9-2d48-4fed-b66b-c20cac2f83c7?plan_id=iotf-service-free-id&service_id=iotf-service-id
>   failed with error message getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
>   bluemix-staging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com

I can't create a new service as well. Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: There was a DNS problem yesterday with the IoT Foundation service but it has now been resolved. Are you still experiencing the problem?  If so, please let us know your org ID.

Comment: You really should accept Valerie's answer if it explained your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a DNS problem on May 5th but it has now been resolved.